# to get the parameter from the url in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page add recommendation and same page for the edit recommendation when I click on the add recommendation the recommendation Id is null in the URL, but when I go the page by clicking the recommendation link it will show that respective Id for the recommendation, in URL it is showing but how to get that Id from the URL to use it.

My code is:

```
.state('Admin.AddRecommendation',{
            url: "/AddRecommendation/:recoId",
            templateUrl: "views/AddRecommendation.html",
            params: {recoId:null},
})
```

controller.js:

```
 $scope.addRecommendation = function(){
        var id = $routeParams.recoId;
        console.log(id);
```

So where I am doing it wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What router you use?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand

Comment: I think he is using `ui-router`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are defining `recoId` in the url, you don't need `params: {recoId:null},`

```
.state('Admin.AddRecommendation',{
            url: "/AddRecommendation/:recoId",
            templateUrl: "views/AddRecommendation.html"
})
```

You can access the params in the controller by injecting `$stateParams`

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $scope.addRecommendation = function(){
        var id = $stateParams.recoId;
        console.log(id);  
    }
}]);
```

If you are using components, `$stateParams` is deprecated in favor of `$transition$` 
However, it is not as straightforward to implement that: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3110#issuecomment-271101827

Basically, you can use it as

```
.component('foo', {
    bindings: { $transition$: '<' },
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
});

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.addRecommendation = function(){
        var id = vm.$transition$.params().recoId;
        console.log(id);  
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the query params from the URL when using ui-router, you can use

In your controller.js:

```
$state.params
```

This will give you all the params in the URL. To get specific param:

```
$state.params[<your-query-param>]
```

EDIT: In your question, instead of `$routeParams`, use `$state`

Comment: Yes I have used it but it is giving an error that "Cannot read property 'recoId' of undefine"

Comment: Could you check what does console.log($state.params) outputs?

Comment: "Cannot read property 'params' of undefined" after console.log state.params